# posibility to let panorama camera follow object so you can always see all sides of object when it moves

Tags: camera, video, panoramic

Is it possible in blender to position the panorama or other camera in a way so you can see your object/character always from every side in a 3d environment?
I want the user see a movie but let them decide if they want a back front left or right view of a character.

Hope somebody already did this and can tell me how to setup.

Comment: you could just add 4 cams - and constraint their movement to your objects movement.

Comment: The problem isn't setting up the cameras, but creating the 3d video that the user will see. There are a handful of 3d output formats, like the one from Apple and the one Facebook uses, but they're mostly proprietary and Blender doesn't have a way to output them.

Comment: Probably you have to render 4 videos and merge them with a specific software.